# ERROR: could not find driver - Using PDO with MS Access database

Tags: php, sql, ms-access, pdo

## Background:

I've got a fully working Microsoft Access DB. I've made a database connection class and just a simple page that includes the class and fires off a simple SQL code. I know the code is right as it was working fine a few weeks ago. However, in between then and now I installed PHP, MySQL, set up my IIS and installed PHPMyAdmin. (We were having problems with our servers so tried going localhost but it was resolved before I fully used PHPMyAdmin).

So now I've got my connection class and simple php page onto the server (using FTP). However, when I run the same query I used a few weeks ago i'm now getting the error message:

```
ERROR:could not find driver. Warning: file_put_contents(connection.errors.txt) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in E:\kunden\blah\blah\blah\www\simpleTest.php on line 31
```

## The Code

#### connectionClass.php:

```
class connection{

public $con;
private $dbName;

function __construct(){
$this->dbName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "../database/db.mdb";
 }

function connect(){
    $this->con = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$this->dbName; Uid=Admin; Pwd=;");
    $this->con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $this->con;
 }   
}
```

#### simpleTest.php

```
if (!ini_get('display_errors')) {
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
}

try{
include_once 'classes/connectionClass.php';

//get the DB connection
$con = new connection();
$pdoConnection = $con->connect();

//query the DB
$sql = $pdoConnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM celebs");
$result = $sql->execute();
while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {        
    echo $row['firstname'];
    echo $row['surname'];
 }

} catch (Exception $e){
echo 'ERROR:'.$e->getMessage();
file_put_contents('connection.errors.txt', $e->getMessage().PHP_EOL,FILE_APPEND);
}
```

I've not changed the code and was wondering if setting up PHP, MySQL, IIS and PHPMyAdmin has done something to prevent me from my code working? I've looked in phpinfo(); but i'm not really sure what to be looking for.

Any help is MUCH appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: In addition, after some de-bugging - i'm fairly certain the error revolves around the code in simpleTest.php after trying to make a new connection...

Comment: Have your test page `echo 8 * PHP_INT_SIZE` and let us know what it reports. (It should be either "32" or "64".)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response - its showing '32'.

Comment: Okay, good. Now look at the `phpinfo()` page again and see if 'odbc' appears in the list of enabled PDO drivers, like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aSnb3.png).

Comment: PDO Driver says 'no value' - so it hasn't been enabled. Do you know off the top of your head how to enable ODBC driver?

Comment: In "php.ini", see if the line `extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll` starts with a semi-colon (commented out). If so, remove the semi-colon and see if that enables PDO_ODBC.

Comment: Went into php.ini, found the code but it didn't start with a semi colon. It showed: [PHP_PDO_ODBC]
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll . However, as I scrolled up past more 'extensions', there was a line of code at the top that was ; End:

Comment: @GordThompson: Upon looking in the ODBC Data Source Administrator, I saw that *.mdb was in the list and when clicked an error message popped up stating 'The setup routines for the Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb) ODBC driver could not be found'. However when I try to 'Add' a new driver the only option is 'SQL Server' =/

Comment: Sounds like your Access ODBC configuration might be damaged. You could try downloading and installing the 32-bit version of the Access Database Engine from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255) and then use `DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}`.

Comment: I'm a little hesitant of downloading new drivers, the reason being is that my company's website is already running off the same Access DB and that's written in .asp - i'm re-writing the website in PHP and uploading to a different server (for development purposes). Would installing the new driver affect the connection between the company's website and the Access DB do you think?

Comment: ..in addition, I went into php.ini and found that extension_dir = "ext" had a semi-colon in front. I removed the semi-colon, saved the php.ini file and restarted the server but phpinfo() still shows no ODBC driver.

Comment: Check your `phpinfo()` page again. Do you have a `com_dotnet` section like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HgLqG.png)?

Comment: Yes, and all the values are the same as the ones in that image.

Comment: As stated earlier, the code was working a couple of weeks ago and I'm wondering if any IIS settings that I changed may have affected it?

Comment: Something seems to have broken your Access ODBC configuration. Probably not IIS settings *per se*, but in any case PDO_ODBC is not the best choice for working with an Access database on a Windows server. See my answer for details.

Comment: I see. I really wish I knew what it was! Yeah I know, it's not my first choice my superior wants an Access DB with PHP, which is certainly not helping proceedings. I'll have a go at integrating your answer in my code, thank you ever so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manipulating an Access database from PHP via ODBC has some serious limitations that affect both PDO and the older `odbc_exec` methods. If you are using a Windows server and you *absolutely must* use an Access database back-end (which is [strongly discouraged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653753.aspx#access_database)) I would recommend that you use ADO under `com_dotnet` like this:

```php
<?php
// this code requires the following php.ini directive:
//
// extension=php_com_dotnet.dll

$con = new COM("ADODB.Connection"); 
$con->Open(
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" .
        "Data Source=C:\\Users\\Public\\mdbTest.mdb");
$rst = new COM("ADODB.Recordset");
$rst->Open("SELECT * FROM celebs", $con, 1, 3);  // adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
while (!$rst->EOF) {
    echo $rst["firstname"]->Value . " " . $rst["surname"]->Value . "<br/>";
    $rst->MoveNext;
}
$rst->Close();
$con->Close();
```

This is especially true if you ever need full Unicode character support or expect to be manipulating binary objects.

Comment: Thank you! This has brought back a few results but not all. It shows around 20 results then an error message: Catchable fatal error: Object of class variant could not be converted to string in E:\blah\blah\blag\blah\www\simpleTest.php on line 21.

Line 21 is:  echo $rst["firstname"] . " " . $rst["surname"] . "<br/>";

Comment: Sorry just another thing (just for clarification); in your commented code you've put adOpenKeyset and adLockOptimistic. Im not too familiar with this syntax, why have you used this?

Comment: @TimJohnstone re: errors - I forgot the to specify the `->Value` properties so it was choking on Null values, sorry. (Code updated.) re: `adOpenKeySet` etc. - See [CursorTypeEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681771%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [LockTypeEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680855%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: You sir have been so helpful, I grant thee with legendary status! :) . Got it working! Looking back the comments, it's probably been a good thing that my PDO driver isn't working as I didn't realise it has limitations. So what you've posted is SQL with ADO instead of SQL with PDO? I've never seen the syntax for ADO before so I will need to read more into it. As the website i'm replicating has many SQL statements, do I need to use $con->Open() command for every SQL statement I use? Would making a connectionClass with the code you've supplied be an option?

Comment: @TimJohnstone I see no reason why your connectionClass couldn't create, open, and return a `COM("ADODB.Connection")` object just like it could for a PDO connection object. And yes, the SQL is the same (Access SQL) it's just the "pipe" through which you send it is an ADO "pipe" instead of a PDO "pipe".

Comment: Fantastic, thank you for clearing that up for me. I'm sorry but I have just one more question: In my connectionClass (PDO) I have the line - $this->con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); - would an ADO equivalent be used, if there is one?

Comment: @TimJohnstone That shouldn't be necessary. The default behaviour for the `COM("ADODB.Connection")` object is to throw exceptions when "bad things" happen (and that's what the `setAttribute` call is telling PDO to do).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! Massive props to you sir.